# Implement a schematic, what's needed?

Tags: schematics, lora

I'm a novice who's looking to jump in the (low power) deep end.

I want to create a breakout board for a Heltec HT-CT62 module.

I would like to know if I need to integrate the entire power schematic along with the USB schematic. The module will just be powered from USB so I'm not sure if the Power element is needed, but the more I think about it, it will be needed.

[Link to Heltec HT-CT62 Schematic](https://resource.heltec.cn/download/HT-CT62/HT-CT62_Reference_Design.pdf)

My current implementation:
[image: Image of Schematic]

I'm sure there's much more I can do, so if you have any suggestions I'll be open to those too!

Comment: you need to show the 10n/100nF caps you are going to use between all power pins to ground

Comment: Thanks, @Neil_UK ; if I understand correctly (after some research), this is a decoupling capacitor?
Do I need one between every pin from U1's Vcc to GND? Or can I just have one between Vcc and GND?

Comment: With small ceramic caps costing approximately zero, there is no reason NOT to put a cap between every VCC pin and the nearest possible point on GND. They keep the power supplies clean at the IC power pins. Not doing it can cause all sorts of 'difficult to debug' problems. The phrase [spoil-the-ship-for-a-haporth-of-tar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449246/whats-a-modern-alternative-idiom-to-dont-spoil-the-ship-for-a-haporth-of-tar) could have been penned for leaving those caps out in this situation. Once all those are on the VCC pins, then use one 10uF for the whole board.

Comment: Great, thanks! From what I can tell, there is only one Vcc (although it's labelled Vdd?), and I've placed a 100nF alongside this. I believe this is the only location.

Answer (score 0):

The ESP32 has maximum rating of 3.6V.

It will damage if you give it 5V.

Also you might want to double check a few things.

The USB-C resistors are on wrong pins.

And 32 kHz crystals rarely have such large capacitances of 22pF.

You might not want to copy 3rd party schematics. Espressif has example schematics for their modules.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct that it appears the module typical is 3.3V; I'll look into this.

I'll review the issue with the USB-C resistors; I've not been able to find a massively useful explanation as to what P1 represents on the USB is within the vendor schematic; I've assumed it USB 2.0 and found another vendor pinout that seemed to match. 

I also used the capacitance from the schematic, how would I go about finding the correct capacitance?

Comment: Espressif should have example designs and documentation how to use their chips and modules. Generally manufacturer documentation tells you with what kind of crystals the module is designed to work. Failing that, the capacitance depends on which crystal you will buy, as it's the crystal which is intended to work with some specific capacitance to run at correct speed.

Comment: I see, thanks! This module I'm using is a pre-built module ([link to module](https://heltec.org/project/ht-ct62/)). Does this change how I should implement the ESP, or should I still try and stick with Espressif's?